# Tilde using a mac keyboard running on Windows 7?

Tags: mac, keyboard

What's the shortcut for TILDE (`~`) using a mac keyboard running on Windows 7?

Comment: Does `ALT+N`, `Space` work, as in Mac OS X?

Comment: Do you want just a tilde (~) or a tilde over an N (ñ, Ñ)?

Comment: What type of hardware? PC or Mac under Bootcamp?

Comment: What keyboard layout?

Answer (score 6):

Try holding <kbd>alt</kbd> and typing <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> on the **numeric keypad**

This is for the bare ~ . If you need Ñ use <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> and if you need ñ type <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>. You can discover more using charmap.exe

Apparently this requires a [registry setting](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm). Mine was enabled by default on XP, so check this if it doesn't work:

> Alas, this appears to require a
>   registry setting. It was already set
>   on my computer, but some readers
>   report that this method didn't work
>   for them, and this is probably why. If
>   you don't know what the registry is,
>   please don't try this. Under
>   HKEY_Current_User/Control Panel/Input
>   Method, set EnableHexNumpad to "1". If
>   you have to add it, set the type to be
>   REG_SZ.

Answer (score 4):

Turn on the language bar (right-click on the clock, and select toolbars->language bar)
Then select English (United states) instead of english (united kingdom). That will give you a tilde...

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> (hold down the right '<kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd>' key and hit <kbd>n</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when using Microsoft Remote Desktop. The On-screen keyboard is helpful but running Windows 10 the shortcut is mapped to <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> on Mac

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are running a Windows (i.e. 11) on a virtual machine (i.e. VirtualBox) on an Apple (Mac) native machine/hardware, you can get the tilde (~) with <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>:

```
 C:\> ~
```